# Technique to improve MIP solve time

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

Was on a webinar and the presenter mentioned that modelers should "slice" in certain contexts to reduce MIP solve time. The context was in sending a Minimum Cost Network Flow Problem. I believe he was referring to pre-evaluating Binary variables in some way. Possibly stacking them in a matrix? The effect was to reduce the solve time. Is anyone aware of this technique? Can't find a reference.

EDIT: some more color. When doing a worker scheduling problem, it's common sense to use the workers availability for a given time period(1 available or 0 unavailable, but not a decision variable) to reduce the number of decision variable created. I believe this was the reference. Simply ensuring you don't create decision variables that we know the value of prior to solving.

Comment: You're not mixing up terms and thinking of cutting planes? Never heard of the word slice in this context.

Comment: @Johan Lofberg I think he is referring to Pete Cacioppi in http://www.gurobi.com/company/events/webinars-2019-six-life-lessons-you-didnt-learn-from-your-OR-program which will have another session April 24 at 3 PM CET.

Comment: Yes that's where I heard it referred, me neither so wanted to explore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave that talk. The term "slice" for iterating over a subset of indicies based on an outer set of indicies was originally invented by Robert Fourer for AMPL (AFAIK). I believe this term appears in the AMPL documentation, and I'll swear on a stack of Bibles that I've heard it used this way both by Bob himself and by senior Gurobi people. At any rate, the documentation [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_tuplelist.html) does a good job of describing what I'm talking about, and you can see different forms of slicing in action in the netflow example [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/quickstart_windows/py_netflow_py_example.html) or [here](https://github.com/ticdat/ticdat/blob/master/examples/gurobipy/simplest_examples/netflow.py). Sorry if I confused you with this term.

Comment: Thanks Pete. Is it a correct statement then that this would save time on the front end during model building, but would leave the number of constraints and the formulation unchanged?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct.